# microbenchmark as data frame or matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, microbenchmark

is there any way to transform output of function `microbenchmark::microbenchmark` into the data frame or matrix?

For example

```
v <- rnorm(100)
m <- microbenchmark(mean(v), sum(v))
```

The output

```
Unit: nanoseconds
   expr  min     lq    mean median   uq   max neval
mean(v) 6568 6979.5 9348.19   7390 7390 54600   100
 sum(v)    0    1.0  353.57    411  411  8211   100
```

I want to use this statistics later so I thought about saving the result as data frame. But `as.data.frame(m)` doesn't work.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will return a data.frame:

```
summary(m)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can save `m` as a dataframe with the following code:

```
m <- summary(microbenchmark(mean(v), sum(v))) #note the addition of summary
m.df<- data.frame(m)
```